# The "Improve Edit" button edits the original post

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I stumbled across [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20308910), which I found pretty good, but it needed a bit more improvement.

[image]

However, when I clicked on *Improve Edit*, the post I was editing was the original post, not the suggested edit.

[image]

I don't want to redo all the editing that this user already suggested, so I just skipped the edit, but this feels like a bug.

Comment: Looking through my post, and checking the suggested edit, turns out it was already rejected when I clicked _Improve Edit_. So, I got an already rejected edit in my review queue?

Comment: Review is known to have a few race conditions so it is possible that your review task is invalidated the moment it is fetched.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you thought this edit looked good. Two others already agreed to disagree with you, and I agree with them.

Comment: @usr2564301 I'd love to hear your thoughts on this, I'm open to learning. I thought it was a good edit because it improved the readability of the code, while making the naming correspond better with what the variables actually are.